# Two Way Binding Bootstrap-Vue Tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, two-way-binding

I am trying to use two way data binding using v-model on `bootstrap-vue` table. But the value on the table does not change when the value changes.

I try to change data with a input text.

```html
<template>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" v-model="items"></b-table>

    <span>The Value: {{value}} </span>
    <b-form-input v-model="value"></b-form-input>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        value = '',
        fields: ['field', 'value',],
        items: [
          { field: 'Field of Value', value: this.value},
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

given value from form input changes the span text but does not change `b-table` value?

Comment: It's because the `value` property of the first object in the `items` array is initialized with `this.value`, but updating `this.value` does not automatically update the `items[0].value` string.

Comment: @thibautg do you have an idea how to work it?

Comment: Use `<b-form-input v-model="items[0].value"></b-form-input>`

Comment: Can i ask what it is you're trying to attempt? For me it doesn't really make sense to use a table if you only have one item

Comment: @Hiws it is not one item more like trying to create a table with a response from a web service, every change in input it makes request from a restful web service and it returns a series of data. I made it one item to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `items` prop instead of `v-model` directive :

```
  <b-table striped hover  :fields="fields" :items="items"></b-table>
```

`b-table` items prop is one way binding.

You should use watch property in order to make that reactive :

```
 export default {
    data() {
      return {
        value : '',
        fields: ['field', 'value',],
        items: [
          { field: 'Field of Value', value: this.value},
        ]
      }
    },
   watch:{
   value(newVal){
   this.items[0].value=this.value;
    this.$set(this.items,0,this.items[0])

    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: It gives an compile error since I use :items="items" for two times.

Comment: ah ok i made an error by duplicating the items prop

Comment: oh yes. But unfortunately <b-table striped hover  :fields="fields" :items="items"></b-table> doesn't work either. It changes nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where do you cal value(newVal) function?

Comment: no need to call it, learn more about watchers [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Comment: that means you're observing any change in value property and then proceed if there's any change

Comment: Is this working on you? I must doing something work.

Comment: Yes it works fine for me check this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/BaBPJJL?editors=1010)

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim then when there are multiple rows, I should detect current row index by checking <tr  class="b-table-row-selected" /> ?